# Eigenvalues and inverse of a Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, toeplitz-matrices

Given the Toeplitz matrix

$$X = \begin{pmatrix}
  ~~~~\textbf{1} ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{d} ~~~~0 ~~~~0 ~~~~0 ~~~~\textbf{d}~~~~ \\
  ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{1} ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{d} ~~~~0 ~~~~0 ~~~~0~~~~ \\
  ~~~~\textbf{d} ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{1} ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{d} ~~~~0 ~~~~0~~~~ \\
  ~~~~0 ~~~~\textbf{d} ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{1} ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{d} ~~~~0~~~~ \\
  ~~~~0 ~~~~0 ~~~~\textbf{d} ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{1} ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{d}~~~~ \\
  ~~~~0 ~~~~0 ~~~~0 ~~~~\textbf{d} ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{1} ~~~\textbf{c}~~~~ \\
  ~~~~\textbf{d} ~~~~0 ~~~~0 ~~~~0 ~~~~\textbf{d} ~~~~\textbf{c} ~~~~\textbf{1}~~~~ \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

where $d$ and $c$ are different values between $-1$ and $0$. Furthermore,

$$2c + 2d = -1$$

My questions are to find expressions for

1. Second largest eigenvalue modulus (SLEM) or eigenvalues
2. Inverse of $X$

Thanks

Comment: $c$ and $d$ will have to be in the interval $[-\frac{1}{2}, 0]$ in order the have the relation $2c+2d=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$1-\sqrt{2} c$ is the second largest eigenvalue. For $c=-\frac{1}{2}$ it gives the second largest modulus. 
According to maple this is the determinant:
$$ (2d-1)(-1+2c^2)(2c^4-4c^2+2dc^2-4d^3+2d-2d^2+1) . $$